Reading different data types via Modbus RTU on ESP32
I am currently running Modbus RTU via RS485 on ESP32 to read data from the Modbus Slave emulator. The code is able to read/write from the virtual PLCs using the ArduinoModbus library (I had to adjust a few parts since it doesn't support ESP32). However, the library still can't read/write other data types (float, long, double...) other than binary and int. I'm using PlatformIO in VSCode.
ArduinoModbus
ArduinoR485
Modbus Slave emulator
Here is the modified read() function that I'm testing in the library:
long ModbusClient::read()
{
  if (_available <= 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  long result = -1;

  switch (_type) {
    case COILS:
    case DISCRETE_INPUTS:
      result = ((uint8_t*)_values)[_read];
      if (result != -1) {
      _available--;
      _read++;
      }
      break;

    case HOLDING_REGISTERS:
    case INPUT_REGISTERS:
      if (_available >= 2) {
        result = ((uint16_t*)_values)[_read];
        result = (result << 16) | ((uint16_t*)_values)[_read + 1];
        if (result != -1) {
          _available -= 2;
          _read += 2;
        }
      }
      break;

    default:
      break; 
  }
  return result;
}

P/S: Alternatively, the comments suggest using another function in the library, but I'm still studying it:
long ModbusClient::holdingRegisterRead(int id, int address)
{
  uint16_t value;

  modbus_set_slave(_mb, id);
  
  if (modbus_read_registers(_mb, address, 1, &value) < 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  return value;
}

My main() loop:
void loop() {
  readHoldingRegisterValues();

  delay(5000);
  Serial.println();
}

void readHoldingRegisterValues() {
  Serial.print("Reading Input Register values ... ");

  // read 10 Input Register values from (slave) id 1, address 0x00
  if (!ModbusRTUClient.requestFrom(1, HOLDING_REGISTERS, 0x00, 10)) {
    Serial.print("failed! ");
    Serial.println(ModbusRTUClient.lastError());
  } else {
    Serial.println("success");

    while (ModbusRTUClient.available()) {
      Serial.print(ModbusRTUClient.read());
      Serial.print(' ');
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}

Here is the output:
1111170744 0 0 0 0

From my understanding, a register can only contain 16-bit value. Float and double are 32-bit and 64-bit, so I'm trying to read each register in turn, then combine them to get the result.

There are Modbus device supports floating point data, but ArduinoModule library doesn't support float. Floating point data are stored in the IEEE754 format and send via Modbus in Big Endian.

I suppose,

_values

is a uint16_t array, stored as a class field or as a static variable (I'm not familiar with this library). Since modbus doesn't transfer data types, they're only defined in your program and in a client, you can re-write this _values variable and it's usage in library as it suits you. For example, you can change it for a union or a struct:
struct {
   uint16_t uintValues[REG_NUM];
   int16_t  intValues[REG_NUM];
   float    floatValues[REG_NUM];
   etc...
} sValues;

Then you can pass uintValues or floatValues member of sValues (_values) variable in read/write functions depending on which registers with which data types is requested by a client.

Your solution has helped me. I did a little research on data types and unions. Apparently, basic type-casting doesn't work well on bit data types. I added a union then pass the value returned by the 'read()' function in its 'uint8_t' member, then print its 'float' member out.
